# Crystal Reports - Date Range issue when calculating previous year

Tags: vba, date, crystal-reports

When running reports by a date range that then also do a comparison for the previous date range exactly 1 year earlier I am getting different numbers. Example: If I run a report for 01/01/2022 to 09/30/2022 and get a value of $100,000 and then run a comparison report but instead input the dates 01/01/2023 to 09/30/2023 I get different numbers for the previous year. They are close bet never an exact match. My reports have a field called CurrentYear$$ and another called LastYear$$ in the detail section. Then I subtotal those formulas to get a total in either a customer group or product group. These always end up slightly different than if I just have a simple date range report that adds up the extended sales field. It makes no sense to me. Any ideas on why this is happening? When looking at total sales for 2022 there was a $27,000 discrepancy between the two reports.

Thank you for your help!!

**Last Year Formula:**

```
If({tblALX_Data.InvDate}) = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Minimum ({?DateRange})) to DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Maximum ({?DateRange})) 
Then {tblALX_Data.Ext$$} Else 0.00
```

** Current Year Formula:**

```
If({tblALX_Data.InvDate}) = {?DateRange} Then {tblALX_Data.Ext$$} Else 0.00
```

I have everything in the information above.

Comment: Try LastYear:  If ({tblALX_Data.InvDate} >= DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Minimum ({?DateRange})) AND 
    {tblALX_Data.InvDate} <= DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Maximum ({?DateRange}))) 
Then

Comment: Current year: If ({tblALX_Data.InvDate} >= Minimum ({?DateRange}) AND 
    {tblALX_Data.InvDate} <= Maximum ({?DateRange})) 
Then

Comment: Thanks for the changes. They didn't effect the outcome though. Report was still the same. I am starting to think that sometimes Crystal Reports get glitches. I basically re-created the report from scratch, everything the same, but now it is coming up with the correct numbers. I just deleted the old one. Thanks